# Modify variable in java method

Tags: java, methods

how to pass a variable in method in java and modify inside the variable

Comment: You're not modifying your A and B float. The X and Y are not the same value as A and B, you cannot modify those floats from inside the method!

Comment: Primitive types are passed by value in Java. You do not have a reference back to your A and B.

Comment: @Kalenda All types are passed by value in Java, not just primitives.

Comment: @azurefrog You are certainly correct, Java always pass-by-value, but the value being passed is a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this

```
public class prueba {

private static void mod1(float x, float y) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        x = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        y = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("A + B = " + (x+y));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        float a = 0;
        float b = 0;
        mod1(a, b);
}
}
```